# Não consigo exibir uma lista de comentários de um post no template do django

Tags: django, django-templates

Tenho um método chamado get_comments no models que me retorna os comentarios do meu post, mas quando vou exibir no template, somente os posts são exibidos, os commentários não são. O django não me retorna nenhuma exception

**Model**

```
from django.db import models
from authentication.models import User

TYPE_POST = (
   ('0', 'Post'),
   ('1', 'Comment')
)

class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagens/', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reactions = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    type_post = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_POST, default='0')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    commented_post = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

   @property
   def get_comments(self):
       comments = Post.objects.filter(type_post='1', commented_post=self.commented_post)

       return comments

   class Meta:
       ordering = ['-pub_date']
```

**Template**

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <p>post.content</p>
    {% for comment in post.get_comments %}
      <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
      <p>{{ comment.pub_date }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Juliana vc consegue confirmar que vc tem posts criados do tipo 1? Na sua modelagem, seriam comments

Comment: Sim, no shell do django, faço a consulta e ele retorna os posts do tipo 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que pra resolver isso, você precisaria mudar um pouquinho o seu método de recuperar os comentários:

```
   @property
   def get_comments(self):
       comments = Post.objects.filter(type_post='1', commented_post=self)
```

O segredo estaria na parte `commented_post=self` ao invés de `commented_post=self.commented_post`. O segundo está filtrando comentários que foram feitos por ele mesmo como post. O `self` nesse caso vai ser o post onde foi feito o comentário.

Comment: Obrigada, consegui resolver!

Comment: Nice! Aproveitando, não sei se vc já conhece, mas temos um grupo de Django no telegram bem bacana. Se vc já usar e tiver interesse: https://t.me/djangobrasil